# How to build uri from url and port number

Tags: c#

Currently, to build a valid `Uri` I'm doing:

```
var uri = new Uri(myUrl);
url = string.Format("{0}:{1}{2}/", uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), myPort, uri.LocalPath == "/" ? string.Empty : uri.LocalPath);
```

`myUrl` can have paths, ie. can be `http://localhost` or `http://1.2.3.4/somepath`

Is there a better way to build the uri based on url and port?

Comment: Use a [`UriBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Lee Great tip. Add as answer to I can mark it as such!